# Reducing code for iterating over the same list with nested for loops but with different variables

Tags: python, list, for-loop, iteration, reducing

Is there any in build python iterating tool that reduces 3 row of for loops into one row?
Here are the nested for loops that I want to reduce.

```
some_list = ["AB", "CD", "EF", "GH"]

for word_1 in some_list:
    for word_2 in some_list:
        for word_3 in some_list:
            print(word_1, word_2, word_3) #Outputs all different combinations
```

I have tried the following but with no success:

```
some_list = ["AB", "CD", "EF", "GH"]

for word_1 ,word_2, word_3 in zip(some_list, some_list, some_list):
    print(word_1 , word_2, word_3) #Outputs parallel elements, which is not what I want.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is, it's [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html).

```python
from itertools import product

some_list = ["AB", "CD", "EF", "GH"]

for word_1 ,word_2, word_3 in product(some_list, repeat=3):
    print(word_1 , word_2, word_3)
```

You can also use tuple unpacking to make it even more concise, like this

```python
some_list = ["AB", "CD", "EF", "GH"]

for words in product(some_list, repeat=3):
    print(*words)
```

Output (in both cases):

```
AB AB AB
AB AB CD
AB AB EF
AB AB GH
AB CD AB
AB CD CD
AB CD EF
AB CD GH
AB EF AB
AB EF CD
...
```